# Passing variable from web api controller method to filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I want to send appId variable value to filter

```
// GET api/filter
[CustomFilter]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{

   var  appId = 123;
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I can use either OnActionExecuting or OnActionExecuted method

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

           //here i want to access appId value

}
```

I know how to access parameter values using querystring

Comment: ok got it,,actually issue is i have to send dynamic value of appid to filter,,how will i achieve that

Comment: Where is the value coming from?

Comment: I have same issue . please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the controller action method, set the value in the `Properties` dictionary of the request object, like this: `Request.Properties["AppId"] = 123;`.

In the `OnActionExecuted` method of the filter, retrieve it like this: `actionContext.Request.Properties["AppId"]`.

BTW, you must use the `OnActionExecuted` method of the filter, if the value is set in the action method. The `OnActionExecuting` method runs before the action method is executed.